# Cant enable gdm3 after following a tutorial on how to remove KDE from ubuntu

Tags: kde, boot-repair, 21.04

Every time I startup I now have to press ctrl + alt + f3 and type something along the lines of

`sudo systemctl start gdm3`

if I don't do that then my pc will just be stuck on the bios logo and nothing else.

This is the tutorial I followed https://trendoceans.com/how-to-remove-the-kde-plasma-environment-in-ubuntu/

when I try

`sudo systemctl enable gdm3`

I get

```
Synchronizing state of gdm3.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gdm3
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

edit: I found the fix which was `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gme3` thanks person on reddit

Comment: I'm not sure this is a very good guide. The reason that Ubuntu comes in so many official [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) is because changing the desktop environment on an installed system is incredibly messy. That's because a DE is made up of dozens of interworking packages. When you removed all of those KDE packages you may have also removed dependencies for GNOME as well. One of the reasons given in that error is missing dependencies. Have you tried to reinstall GNOME? If that doesn't work, you may end up realizing it's more prudent to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: @ImLemon Thank you for the tip. Just to be sure, you meant `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` (because it didn't work for me with `sudo dpgk-reconfigure gme3`). Also, it worked for me only after starting gdm3 (`sudo systemctl start gdm3`).

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar type of problem. This is happened because of missing the **Install** in your **gdm3.service** file. To solve this, firstly you have to go `/lib/systemd/system/` directory and then open the **gdm3.service** file at any editor. As like: `sudo nano gdm3.service`.

After adding:

> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target

To the bottom of `gdm3.service` unit file, it fixes the issue of me running `systemctl enable gdm3`.
You can now successfully able to enable gdm3.

Comment: I had the same exact issue as OP, and this allowed me to enable gdm3 through systemctl, but my boot was still messed up. `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` was what fixed it for me.

Comment: @BadrB your comment is helpful. it will also be helpful for me too.

Comment: What you described did solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type
`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`
then reboot and you sgould go straigjt to a desktop.
If you want to go back then
`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
to take you straight to the console on boot.
And if all else fails `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`